# How to simplify repeated redirections in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

How to simplify the following command line in bash:

```
make install 1>/dev/null && update-initramfs -k all -u 1>/dev/null
```

I want to redirect all stdout output from both commands to /dev/null.

Comment: A different but effective workaround would be to use `make -s`. Perhaps `update-initramfs` has a similar option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A trivial simplification is to remove the 1s, as they are the default file descriptors for output redirection.

```
make install >/dev/null && update-initramfs -k all -u >/dev/null
```

But I suspect you are looking for a command group to aggregate the standard output:

```
{ make install && update-initramfs -k all -u; } > /dev/null
```